Smooth approximation of $L^p$ functions with zero average
Let $U \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ be a bounded open set and suppose that $f : U \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is in the Banach space $L^p(U)$ for some $1 \leq p < \infty$, that is,
$$
    \int_U |f|^p dx < \infty.
$$
If $U$ is a Lipschitz domain, then $C^\infty(\overline U)$ is a dense subset of $L^p(U)$.
Now let $X \subseteq L^p(U)$ be the functions with zero average, that is,
$$
X := \left\{ f \in L^p(U) : \int_U f dx = 0 \right\}
.
$$
Is $X \cap C^\infty(\overline U)$ a dense subset of $X$?

Is $U$ bounded?

Take an approximating sequence $\bar{f}_n$ of smooth functions (not necessarily of zero average) and define a new sequence $f_n = \bar{f}_n - |U|^{-1} \int \bar{f}_n$. Since convergence in $L^p$ implies convergence of averages its easy to see this approximating sequence works.
